# Main div not scaling properly with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a html table thats inside a div that is itself inside another div.

```
<div id='mainHolder'>
    <div id='primaryContent'>
        <table>moar content</table>
    </div>
    <div id='secondaryContent'></div>
</div>
```

The problem i have right now is that the 'mainHolder' does not scale properly when i dynamically add content in the table. But the 'primaryContent' div does scale properly.

Here is a link to the complete solution. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2MsH/2/)

Thanks for any reply :)

Comment: Your table markup is invalid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/table

Comment: take a look at the complete thing, its linked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/g2MsH/6/

```
.container:after {
    clear:both;
    content: ".";
    display:block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;    
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely, its because i didnt clear:both ? does the property :after runs after it is rendered ? What about the content attribute, a little more elaboration would be nice.

Comment: It's because floated element is taken out of normal document flow and its height is not considered when calculating the height of the containing element. :after creates a pseudo element after the mentioned element. Read more about after here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/::after And about float here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow: hidden` to container. Its a clearing issue. You have a float to the left on mainContent which isnt cleared.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2MsH/5/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for

```
clear:both; // in .container
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2MsH/4/